# Проблема сборки Андроид приложения

Tags: android, java

Добрый день. Возникла ошибка сбоки приложения под андроид типа:

> Error:(7, -1) android-apt-compiler:
>   [MchsSprav_main]
>   ...MchsSprav_main/res/values/styles.xml:7:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for
>   item: No resource found that matches
>   the given name
>   'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
>   ...MchsSprav_main/res/values-v14/styles.xml:8:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for
>   item: No resource found that matches
>   the given name
>   'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

Насколько понял, что ресурсы  с описанием темы не находит. Сама либа (support) скачана, но непонятно как его подключить, так как всякие jar подключаются нормально а каталог с res не очень. Среда idea.

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 2):

Обновите Support библиотеки и добавьте в файл build.gradle нужного модуля в раздел dependencies{} строки:

```
dependencies{
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.+'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте решение, предложенное здесь:

[No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21059804/3634725)